# C# -Generics - CLS or IL?

Tags: c#

Are generics parameterized IL or part of CLS ?

Comment: I note that you're asking an "or" question which is not a choice between alternatives. IL is an standardized code format for a specified virtual machine. CLS is a specification for what spec-compliant programming languages are required to produce and consume. I'm not sure what you believe they have to do with each other. Can you explain your question better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are part of the CLI and are detailed in the standard (ECMA 335). The IL uses special instructions and formats that directly encode various generic operations. So, generic code is directly compiled to CIL, which itself uses type variables.

Comment: And the fact that generics wern't in 1.1 but were in the spec means that 1.1 should have been called 0.1.

Comment: Well many Microsoft's products are like that, ASP.NET MVC is another example.

Answer (score 1):

To extend Barry's answer, you can see int? x = 5; in IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0004:  call        System.Nullable<System.Int32>..ctor
```